# How to run multiple methods one by one in c#

Tags: c#

I have 50 to 70 methods in a class. Now I want to run all these methods one by one. Means if method1 completes then method2 starts, method2 ends then method3 starts. Any guidance where to start?

Comment: Create method which execute all your methods in the order you need. Why you cannot write code which execute all methods one by one?

Comment: each method may take its own parameters. i dont know why you even need this. you can get list of all methods by `type.GetMethods()` using reflection but i dont think you can call them correctly since the parameters are not same.

Comment: There are no parameters on any methods. Order is also not important for me. Actually all methods are reading data and writing data which some times take 1-2 hours for one method to complete.

Comment: Down-voted for the complete absence of what you've tried so far.

Comment: @JeffDunlop Sometimes there is no idea about where to start. Not a good decision to down vote. Instead of down vote you have given some advice then it would be beneficial. I have asked for path not code.

Comment: If you don't know where to start the question doesn't belong on SO. Please review the guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = new Something();
    var methods = obj.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public 
                                      | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        method.Invoke(obj, null);
    }
}

public class Something {
    public void TestA() { Console.WriteLine("Running A"); }
    public void TestB() { Console.WriteLine("Running B"); }
    public void TestC() { Console.WriteLine("Running C"); }
    public void TestD() { Console.WriteLine("Running D"); }
    public static void TestE() { Console.WriteLine("Running E"); }
}
```

Yields

```
Running A
Running B
Running C
Running D
Running E
```

Only works with methods that don't take parameters, of course.

Static method added thanks to M.kazem Akhgary's suggestion

Comment: You can also add static. `| BindingFlags.Static`. also static methods gets invoked without problem.

Comment: This will work only if Class have not methods which no need for execution

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks, will do

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for the solution. It is working fine. I am converting the above code to meet my requirements I'll inform you about the results. I am sure it will work. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
//place this code under an event

Thread th;
th = new thread(AllMethods);
th.start();
//

//Create a function calling all functions
void AllMethods()
{
    MethodA();
    MethodB();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflection but I am not sure whether it will be executed in the correct order. If your method names are defined in some alphabetical order, then it might run the way you want.

Comment: There is no order required. I just want to execute all the methods one by one so that my system does not hang or blow.

Comment: Reflection is perfect solution then. All  you need is to compile you class using CSharpCodeProvider and then invoke all methods using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

don't worry about that just create a function which call all your class methods one by one, there is no system crash issue.. 
in this function control goes for calling method from top to bottom no alphabet order required, means just put the methods in sequence

```
void FnCallingAllMethods()
 {
 Method1();
 Method2();
 Method3(); 
. 
. 
. 
}
```

In these sequence when one method is successfully completed then control jumps to another one.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, what Rob said. Just replace the “Console.WriteLine….” with the actions you want to take and all is well. You can also keep adding to the list indefinitely. However, as Rob mentioned, this option will not work with parameters.

So, another option is to create the individual programs and create a primary program that will execute all of them in order. Say for example, you want to create a text document that lists all your files in a folder; then you want a program (or method) to email that list out.

You certainly don’t want the second program to try emailing the list if the list has not finished generating. So you need a “WaitForExit” option. In the code below, I have created 5 programs. Four programs that perform 4 different tasks independently, and a primary program to trigger each one of them in succession.

Here again, add or remove as many sections as you need for your project. 
 Thanks and I hope this helps someone in the future.

Side note: once you create the programs in Visual Studio, run the “build” option under “Tools” and then run the “Batch Build” (also under “Tools). This will generate the “.exe” files you need.

Enjoy.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CallMultipleMethods2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Start first application.
                Process firstProc = new Process();
                firstProc.StartInfo.FileName = "c:/MyPrograms/program1.exe";
                firstProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                firstProc.Start();

                firstProc.WaitForExit();

                //You may want to perform different actions depending on the exit code.
                Console.WriteLine("First process completed: " + firstProc.ExitCode);
                // End of first application

                // Start second application
                Process secondProc = new Process();
                secondProc.StartInfo.FileName = "c:/MyPrograms/program2.exe";
                secondProc.Start();

                secondProc.WaitForExit();

                Console.WriteLine("Second process completed: " + secondProc.ExitCode);
                // End of second application

                // Start third application
                Process thirdProc = new Process();
                thirdProc.StartInfo.FileName = "c:/MyPrograms/program3.exe";
                thirdProc.Start();

                thirdProc.WaitForExit();

                Console.WriteLine("Third process completed: " + thirdProc.ExitCode);
                // End of third application

                // Start fourth application
                Process fourthProc = new Process();
                fourthProc.StartInfo.FileName = "c:/MyPrograms/program4.exe";
                fourthProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                fourthProc.Start();

                fourthProc.WaitForExit();

                Console.WriteLine("Fourth process completed: " + fourthProc.ExitCode);
                // End of fourth application
            }

            // catch on error
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred!!!: " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```